# Video Player For Xamarin That supports HTTP Video Streams

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, video-player

I am searching for a video player that can play video streams from a http url and supports at least Google API 21 (Lollipop). I am not looking for High End player, but it should support Basic Volume control, full screen support and play/pause option.

I tried using [ExoPlayerXamarin](https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin), but the documentation isn't proper and I couldn't understand it. I tried to launch its Sample App, but the sample app doesn't seem to have any `.sln` file associated with it and the the `MvvmCross` won't run on my system.

Currently, I am using the built in Xamarin videoplayer and I'd have to write the whole code for play/pause, full screen etc. I'm trying to avoid to re-invent the wheel.

If anyone have suggestions, please link me up.

Comment: Have you checked my answer, any update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently, I am using the built in Xamarin videoplayer and I'd have to write the whole code for play/pause, full screen etc. I'm trying to avoid to re-invent the wheel.

For the "built in Xamarin videoplayer" I think you mean the official [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) of google android.

Then you don't need write the whole code for controlling the playing of video, you can simply use [MediaController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) together with `VideoView`, it's a view containing controls for a MediaPlayer. Typically contains the buttons like "Play/Pause", "Rewind", "Fast Forward" and a progress slider. It takes care of synchronizing the controls with the state of the MediaPlayer. For example like this:

```
var videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoview);
var mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.SetVideoURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("video url goes here"));
mediaController.SetAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.SetMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.RequestFocus();
videoView.Start();
```

If users tap on the video, the controller will be shown/ hide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , It is working as it should , Video Player controls are showing and working . Now , I am looking into giving Fullscreen option and showing some other buttons when user touches the screen and fades after some time. If you have some resources regarding that do share.

 Thanks again

Comment: @AnkitPassi, yeah, I think I can give a try on that, but could you please mark this answer and open a new thread on SO? Because that is a new question.